# Angular 7: Overwrite parent class of third party components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to work with many components of a third party library that all extend an abstract class which behavior I have to alter. To make it more clear, see the following lines of sample code:

```js
abstract class ThirdPartyParentClass {
  parentMethod() {
    // I need to alter this method...
  }
}

class ThirdPartyComponent1 extends ThirdPartyParentClass {
  componentMethod() {
    parentMethod();  // ...because it gets called here...
  }
}

class ThirdPartyComponent2 extends ThirdPartyParentClass {
  componentMethod() {
    parentMethod();  // ...and here...
  }
}

// ...and in a few other places.
```

One obvious solution would be to extend the parent class, overwrite the respective method, and duplicate the code of all its components, making them extend my custom parent class instead. However, since the third party library is currently under heavy development, I fear that I would introduce a lot of technical debt by doing so.

Is there another possibility to reach this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good use case for [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
Create your own class and create your custom method :

```
export class MyCustomImplementation {
  parentMethod() {
    // this is the parentMethod altered
  }
}
```

Create and export a function to apply the mixin to your class :

```
export function applyMixins(derived: any, bases: any[]) {
    bases.forEach((base) => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(base.prototype)
        .filter((propertyName) => propertyName.toLowerCase() !== 'constructor')
        .forEach((propertyName) => {
            derived.prototype[propertyName] = base.prototype[propertyName];
        });
    });
}
```

In your ThirdPartyComponent, import and implements your class :

```
class ThirdPartyComponent1 extends ThirdPartyParentClass, implements MyCustonImplementation {
  constructor() {
    super();
    applyMixins(ThirdPartyComponent1, [MyCustomImplementation]);
  }
  componentMethod() {
    parentMethod();  // ...because it gets called here...
  }
}
```

That way, you do not change the tight-coupled inheritance relation between ThirdPartyComponents and ThirdPartyClass, but you can overwrite the method.

I made a [dummy stackblitz implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4e1cr)

Comment: That is a very nice approach! Thank you very much! In my special case, however, ThirdPartyComponent1 is a third-party component. To be more precise, I have a handful of third-party components all extending that parent class and calling this specific method. So by using your approach, I would either have to duplicate all components (which will introduce a lot of technical debt) or extend them. However, in the case of extending, I'm not sure how I should use this approach to alter a method of the grandparent of the component.

Comment: @georg-un : I modified the stackblitz. I created a service in which you can overwrite your third-party component's method without having to create a custom component.

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome and elegant solution! I used this to overwrite the method of the parent class and it works like a charm. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: The only drawback I see is that if they change the name of the method you want to overwrite, you won't notice, it will still compile and you won't have any error during runtime. I don't know if it's likely to appear, if that is the case, I'd check that the custom method is still a part of the component. In case it is not, I'd throw an error to make the application fails fast and loud. I'm glad it helped ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parent or the child classes are injectables you should be able to use class providers:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#aliased-class-providers

When the parent class is an injectable and injected via the constructor in other 3rd party classes you can extend the parent class, overwrite the method and then configure your module to use your class instead of the 3 party parent class.

When the 3rd party child classes are injectables you have to extend all child classes and overwrite the parent method. After that you configure your module.